# Do the squats Zack and Cloud do actually do anything in real life

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique

In the Final Fantasy VII games Zack and Cloud seem to imply that the squats they do are like the ultimate form of exercise with Zack claiming that's really the only exercise he does (ofcause excluding all the work he does on missions for SOLDIER).

I am wondering if in real life what what impact their exercise actually has on the body

[Crisis Core - Final Fantasy VII (Squatting Minigame at 7:15)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QadtQqdCZzw)

Comment: squats work mainly the legs, so it's not 'ultimate' in any way. Also the form is soooo bad, with all the swinging your legs don't really work, they just bounce. So, IRL this would only benefit you if you go for muscular endurance (if you do 100+, and please do them slowly) or if you never did any other exercise before (because even walking is 'exercise' if you don't do it normally).

Comment: I'd agree with LarissaGodzilla. Squats as shown in the game are pretty awful and really only work the legs. But squatting with weights, overhead or front or back squats can be a very effective exercise. http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/raise-the-bar-how-to-master-the-overhead-squat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Memor-X,

If you squat like the video you mentioned, you'll develop knee problems pretty fast. ***So please, don't perform it like that***

As others have mentioned, squat is an awesome body-weight exercise that mainly works the legs. However, there are variations of squats that can work the entire body.

For example, it can be used as a form of cardio exercise by increasing the speed of the repetition. That will increase your heart and lungs' endurance.

You can also include jumping to it. Instead of standing up from the squat position, you jump into the air as high as you can. That increases the intensity and works your heart and lungs as well *(P90X participants should already be aware of that modification)*.

Of course, it can also be modified into a burpee by including planking and jumping to the routine.

Lastly, you can include barbell and weights with it; that works your entire body as well.

Hope this helps.